# How to solve this recursive relation T(n)= 2T(n/2) + 3T(n/5) +n

Tags: recurrence-relation, recursion, master-theorem

I don't think I'm able to solve this using the master's theorem, and solving separately doesn't seem to make sense. How does one go about solving this recursive relation?

T(n)= 2T(n/2) + 3T(n/5) +n

Comment: You may use [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).

Comment: @fade2black is there another method? Im not exactly sure on how to use it.